# CSS 100% height in inner columns

Tags: css, html, height, sticky-footer

UPDATE: http://jsfiddle.net/dSkJb/19/

To clarify, the footer should be at the bottom of the page, and the page should have 100% height at all times, so the middle row should adjust accordingly.  Nothing should overlap the footer, and the footer shouldn't overlap anything.  Essentially, if you have a two row table with a 100% height, you'd accomplish this easily.

---

This is the issue, a div with 100% height that is inside a div with 100% and some text gets bumped down.

http://jsfiddle.net/sandraqu/dSkJb/8/

Is there a way to make the inner div's height relative to its containing div's height?

Original Post Below

---

I am trying to get two inner columns to have a 100% height, and not disturb the sticky footer.  So far I have the sticky footer working in relation to a main container, but am struggling to match the height of #content, #col1, and #col2 to the height of the #container without loosing the sticky footer.

Different articles suggest using height: auto; height: 100%; and min-height (for ie6), but I find height: auto; to interfere with inner div heights.  There are suggestions also for position: relative, floats, display: inline.  Too many options?

Suggestions please :: http://jsfiddle.net/sandraqu/kDCTR/

Comment: Can someone help me move this forward?  I'm trying a UL LI, and that seems to have potential, but there are bugs still.  I'm guessing may be a wrapping div with negative margins might work with a block position absolute at bottom 0.  I'm trying for a multicolumn layout that allows for any one column to be the tallest, dynamically, and have all columns deliver 100% height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Cross Browser Solution](http://jsfiddle.net/bqw48/1/) for IE 8+. In theory though, you could use any method for getting the columns in the middle. I just used `display: table;` and `display: table-cell;`. But the wrapping div does not need to be `display: table;` to work, so you can use `float` tricks, or faux columns, or holy grail, or whatever you want and make it IE 6+ compatible. I'm just to lazy to implement any of those right now. The main goal has been accomplished, I'll let you work on the specifics. :)

Answer (score 0):

First, I'm unsure what you mean by "sticky footer" in this case. A sticky footer is usually something sticks in place while the rest of the page scrolls. However, your example seems to "stick" the footer to the bottom of the container, rather than the bottom of the viewport. Is this correct behavior?

Second, depending on how you want to handle it, there are a couple options for "100% height" columns:

**1) Fake It**

Use a background image which looks like the columns you want. repeat it along the `body`, your `container` OR your `content`, depending on how you want it styled. Please see [A List Apart - Faux Columns](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fauxcolumns/) or Google "CSS Faux Columns" for more information.

This is the best solution if you want an actual sticky footer.

**2) Position your elements**

Add `position: relative` to your `content` div, and `position: absolute; height: 100%;` to the column which will have less content. The column that will have more content will serve to increase the height of your `content` element. Also note that you may want to add a margin to the column with more content, to push it away from the one with less content.

This should allow your columns to push all the way to the footer. This is the better solution if your footer should be at the bottom of the container, rather than at the bottom of the viewport.

See my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e4HXw/) for more details on this technique.

Comment: Either column can be longer than the other at any one time.  I need both of them to independently go full height.  When I apply height:100%, the height goes beyond the main container by about the height of the header.  It seems to simply replicate the height of the container, and not fit the height in the remaining space available.  The footer should stick to the bottom of the page and never overlap any text above it.

Comment: Then fake it with *Faux Columns*

Answer (score 0):

It is a little unclear how you want potential overflow to work on the center content area, and how old of a browser you want to accommodate. For IE8+ I believe this meets your needs: http://jsfiddle.net/dSkJb/51/. Here's a really short content example: http://jsfiddle.net/dSkJb/52/.

*Maybe* with some serious targeted tweaking IE7 could be accommodated (I spent too much time trying to make it work, came close a few times, but was not able to quite get it, so I gave up). IE6 will definitely NOT work with this.

Comment: Good effort.  "Nothing should overlap the footer, and the footer shouldn't overlap anything."

Comment: What do you mean by that? The only thing my footer overlaps is the content and that is only if the content is too long to fit the screen height. If you want a "sticky" footer then either long content is going to get overlapped or it is going to get truncated. What is your intended behavior for long content?